# How to create PHPMailer mx blacklist

Tags: php, phpmailer

I send email via php script + phpmailer

I want to make blacklist mx records check in phpmailer. 
For example,

If email info@mail.com has in mx record domain company.com or company1.com  - my script shouldn't send email to this info@mail.com

I need only mx check before sending email,  not domain check in info@mail.com

Is it real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know the details of phpmailer, but a generic algorithm is:

```
$host = "gmail.com";
$black = array("mail.anexample.com","mail.otherexample.com");
////////
$mxarr = array();
getmxrr($host, $mxarr);
$intersect = array_intersect($mxarr, $black);
if(!count($intersect)>0) {
    echo "ok";
    //sendmail(......);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do that directly from `PHPMailer`
but you can use [getmxrr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmxrr.php) like:

```
getmxrr('mail.com', $mxhosts);
print_r($mxhosts);
```

and check that `array` for your blacklisted domains and choose to send or not the email.